# Elements within navigation resize separately rather than together

Tags: html, css

One of the biggest problems I have with navigation bars is that, whenever trying to put a logo in with a title, I always find that the image resizes itself to much smaller than the text sooner rather than later.

In the case below, I have a title at one end of the navigation/title bar and an image at the other end. When resizing or even on mobile devices, the image becomes very very small.

The html...

```
   <div id="nav">
       <p>Crowes</p>
       <img src="pic.jpg" />
   </div>
```

..and the CSS

```
#nav { 
            background-color: #7E0E0A; 
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px black; 
            padding: 1%; 
            font-size: 5vh; 
            color: white; 
            font-weight: bold; 
            font-family: 'Pacifico'; 
            overflow: auto; 
            width: 100%; 
            z-index: 1;
        }

            #nav p { 
                margin-left: 2%;
                margin-top: 1%; 
                margin-bottom: 1%; 
                float: left;
                color: white;
            }

            #nav img { 
                display: inline-block; 
                width: 6%; 
                vertical-align: middle;
                float: right; 
                border-radius: 50%; 
                border: 2px solid white; 
                margin-right: 3%; 
                opacity: 0.7;
                transition: all 0.2s ease;
            }
```

Comment: Would it be solved using same width for P element?

Comment: Would it be solved by not writing `width:6%`? I mean, what do you want to happen instead of the image being 6% of the window width?

Comment: @MrLister I want it to stay a similar size to the text at all times, even if that text resizes to fit other devices. At the moment I get: http://i.imgur.com/FWbw3PC.png on smaller devices

Comment: Use `width:1em` (or `height:1em`) instead of `width:6%`.

Comment: @FarzadYZ was along the right lines.

Comment: @MrLister Yeah, you're right. Along with using `ems` for margening, too, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not only just changing the size of the elements, it was also their positioning. It all had to be changed to `ems` rather than `%`.

(Nav-specific)

```
#nav { 
            background-color: #7E0E0A; 
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px black; 
            font-size: 2.3em;
            color: white; 
            font-weight: bold; 
            font-family: 'Pacifico'; 
            overflow: auto; 
            width: 100%; 
            z-index: 1;
        }
```

`font-size` to `2.3em`.

(P-specific)

```
            #nav p { 
                margin: 1.3em;
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: middle;
                float: left;
                color: white;
            }
```

`margin` to `1.3em`

(Img-specific)

```
            #nav img { 
                display: inline-block; 
                height: 2.3em; 
                vertical-align: middle;
                float: right; 
                border-radius: 50%; 
                border: 2px solid white; 
                margin: 1em; 
                opacity: 0.7;
                transition: all 0.2s ease;
            }
```

`height` to `2.3em`, as guided by @MrLister and `margin` to `1em`.

Comment: Ans do not forget to use a clearfix on your #nav because of children floats and proper sizing.